# How to track Logstash errors

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am running my elasticsearch and logstash setup in my linux machine. Sometimes my logstash failed to process the file. I suspect there might be an issue so I am very much interested to record the errors in a sepreate file.

Is there any option available to create logstash log file?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are planning to add a "dead letter" feature to logstash 5 (the next release).  Until then, you would have to identify the possible problems yourself, tag the event, and output to a different location based on the tag.